# Why doesn't this batch command work as expected?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file

Here are the commands I enter on the Windows command line:

`> set /P myvalue="Enter a value: " && echo "Here is what you entered: %myvalue%"`

I was expecting that this script would assign user input to `%myvalue%`, and *(upon successful exit from the first command)* would output `%myvalue%` as per the echo command.  The echo statement is not outputting the current value of `%myvalue%`.

If I run the commands separately, and consecutively, I get the expected behavior.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As CodeSampleNotFound mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/1410041/911683), expansion is the culprit here. I managed to find a work around for your example:

```
set /P myvalue="Enter a value: " & echo. | echo "Here is what you entered: %myvalue%"
```

The pipe character alone does not wait for the `set` command to receive it's input before processing the `echo` command, so it was necessary to add an inconsequential command between them. `echo.` generally prints an empty line, but in this case it doesn't, so you get the output:

```
>set /P myvalue="Enter a value: " & echo. | echo "Here is what you entered: %myvalue%"
Enter a value: Test
"Here is what you entered: Test"
```

In this case you don't have the same error checking, but if you're setting a new variable, you can test that it was set with:

```
set /P myvalue="Enter a value: " & echo. | IF NOT "%myvalue%"=="" echo "Here is what you entered: %myvalue%"
```

Answer (score 2):

The variables are expanded one line at at time. 
https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

I played with it for a while and couldn't come up with a way to have it passed along the same line. It does work when the commands are run concurrently as you say.